# How to prove (a+b')(b+c')(c+a') = (a'+b)(b'+c)(c'+a)?

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra

Firstly I expanded both LHS and RHS as following:
LHS: (a+b')(b+c')(c+a') = ab + ac' + b'b + b'c' = ab + ac' + b'c' = abc + ac'c + b'c'c + a'ab + a'ac' + a'b'c' = abc + 0 + 0 + 0 + 0 + a'b'c' = abc + a'b'c'

RHS: (a'+b)(b'+c)(c'+a) = abc + a'b'c'. I get similar expression on RHS and LHS. This is not algebraic expression. To me it seems that both LHS and RHS are in product-of-sums form. How should this boolean equality be proved ?

Comment: You have already proved it by showing that both sides reduce to the same form.

Comment: A graphical method would be perhaps to generate a truth table or a Karnaugh map. I can do that, but I really want to see if boolean equality can be proved with basic axioms of boolean algebra alone.

Comment: Hi Parcly, I assumed that these are a algebraic expressions. If given expressions were in PoS form, can I still prove it with expansion ?

Comment: You've already proved it by expansion.

Comment: A PoS expression can be expanded to SoP expression. Is that statement correct ?

Comment: _Yes_...${}{}{}$

Answer (score 1):

Here's a useful equivalence principle:

**Consensus**

$(P \lor Q) \land (\neg Q \lor R) \land (P \lor R) \Leftrightarrow (P \lor Q) \land (\neg Q \lor R)$

$(P \land Q) \lor (\neg Q \land R) \lor (P \land R) \Leftrightarrow (P \land Q) \lor (\neg Q \land R)$

Applied to your statement:

$$(a + b')(b+c')(c+a')= \text{ (Idempotence)}$$

$$(a + b')(b+c')(c+a')(a + b')(b+c')(c+a')= \text{(Consensus x 3)}$$

$$(a + b')(b+c')(a+c')(c+a')(a+b')(c + b')(b+c')(c+a')(b + a')= \text{(Idempotence x 3)}$$

$$(a + b')(b+c')(a+c')(c+a')(c + b')(b + a')= \text{(Commutation x 6)}$$

$$(b' + a)(c'+b)(c'+a)(a'+c)(b'+c)(a'+b)= \text{(Commutation)}$$

$$(a' + b)(b'+c)(a'+c)(c'+a)(c'+b)(b'+a)= \text{ (Idempotence x 3)}$$

$$(a' + b)(b'+c)(a'+c)(c'+a)(a' + b)(c'+b)(b'+c)(c'+a)(b'+a)= \text{ (Consensus x 3)}$$

$$(a' + b)(b'+c)(c'+a)(a' + b)(b'+c)(c'+a)= \text{ (Idempotence)}$$

$$(a' + b)(b'+c)(c'+a)$$

Comment: Thank you Bram28. Your method is appealing, and satisfying.

Comment: @Digvijay You're welcome! :)